# process.stdin request body nodejs cgi

Tags: node.js, process, cgi, stdin

i make cgi code for nodejs like this

```
#!C:/Program Files/nodejs/node
var sys = require('sys');
sys.puts("Status: 200");
sys.puts("content-type:text/plane; ;charset=utf-8");
sys.puts("");
process.stdin;
```

i will get request body with process.stdin;
but process.stdin has an error "Error: EINVAL, invalid argument"

Comment: Have you checked whether `process.stdin !== null`?